# showing shopping card buttons and the count of items in top of all pages

Tags: asp.net

i want to put a button of shopping card in top of all page and when any on add product to shopping card the count of products in shopping card displayed near the button in top ,i want to know the idea of it
please can any one help me

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information here.  At best all we can say is, "Add a Label control to your master page and set its text to be the current count of items."  Where specifically are you running into trouble?  What code isn't working as you think it should?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Well you definitely need to put this information in your master page. If you're not using master pages, [this article will get you started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx).